# Calculate -3db point in low pass inverting transistor audio amplifier

Tags: transistors, capacitive, frequency-response, common-emitter

### What I am trying to do:

I am looking to find the \$ -3dB \$ frequency for my common emitter transistor amplifier with a capacitor in the feedback loop.

I have somewhat of an idea, but I wanted someone to confirm or correct my understanding.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5yYs8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Notes:*

- *Assume my sine wave is actually audio with a full range of frequency - maybe white noise?*
- *My peak-peak voltage is ~200mV, i.e., I am not saturating the transistor.*

### My Thoughts:

- As the frequency **decreases**, such that, \$ \frac{1}{2\pi FC_{2}} > R_{3}\$, the feedback current from \$ Q_{collector} \$ to \$ Q_{base} \$ is controlled by \$ R_{3} \$, i.e., \$ 400k \Omega \$. Therefore, the gain for the frequencies will be *whatever the gain of the transistor is?*
- As the frequency **increases**, such that, \$ \frac{1}{2\pi FC_{2}} \rightarrow 0 \$, this will essentially short \$ Q_{collector} \$ to \$ Q_{base} \$, which should make the gain \$ 0 \$ for those frequencies.
- Given my above assumptions, if I calculate the frequency at which \$ \frac{1}{2\pi FC_{2}} = R_{3} \$, this will give me the \$ -3dB \$ point?

### Calculating with my assumptions:

Rearranging the capacitive reactance formula:
$$ X_{c} = \frac{1}{2\pi FC} \therefore F = \frac{1}{2\pi CX_{c}}$$

Solving with actual values:

$$ Given: X_{c} = 400k, C = 400pF $$

$$
\frac{1}{2 * pi * 400 * 10^{-12} * 400 * 10^3} = 994.71Hz
$$

So... at \$ \approx 994Hz \$, my gain will \$ -3dB \$ than the gain at say, \$ 20Hz \$, where \$ X_{c} \approx 20M \$ ?

### My question:

Can someone confirm my understanding is correct?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Miller effect?

Comment: @JohnD I am not ... I will google it. Interesting ... I am kind of more curious if my understanding of the transistor part of this is correct though. **I just had another thought** my \$ -3dB \$ gain is in relation to the gain of the circuit, not the source signal, which is an issue. I need to calculate the actual gain of the transistor in order to find how this will effect the source signal, I think.

Comment: Correct, you need the gain of the transistor, which means you need its DC operating point too.

Comment: I do not see the \$gm\$ of the NPN anywhere in your calculation so I'm guessing that you didn't do a **small signal analysis** of this circuit. Without that you cannot determine the voltage gain and the influence of the Miller effect. You might want to read: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa14/lectures/Lecture12-Small%20Signal%20Model-BJT.pdf  or whatever source of information you prefer.

Comment: What is \$ gm \$ ? Also, if I find the gain of the transistor, say it's 10, isn't my \$ -3dB \$ calculation in relation to the DC gain of the transistor?

Comment: *Also, if I find the gain of the transistor, say it's 10,* It doesn't work like that. Either you do this properly or you will be making huge errors. It's OK if you're not willing to study small signal analysis, then just use a simulator (like LTSPice). The Miller effect "enlarges" the base-collector capacitor by that gain. So if your gain was 10 (which it is not) then your 400 pF cap would appear as a 4000 pF cap. This circuit also isn't very suitable for a beginner in analyzing as the biasing (R2, R3) is also a feedback to the input.

Comment: *What is gm ?* Study "small signal analysis".

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will study and update question.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the small signal analysis of a BJT amplifier, perhaps just simulating it in LTSpice would be a good place to start, eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ex3LSexJZmk

Comment: CL simulation shows the gain is not Rc/Rin but 66%. And f-3dB = 1.6kHz which is 60% more BW.  Anyone care to guess why? The gain reduction is very slightly sensitive to hFE and requires a massive value of about 100k to approach Rc/Rin.  For higher ratios of Rc/Rin, like 100, I have always expected the closed loop gain about 50% of this gain for hFE=100 , and unlike H bias, also very much less sensitive to Av=40IcRc

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function is Av=G/(1+GH).
If you had an inverting Op Amp with an AOL of only 10 and a negative feedback Resistance ratio of 10:1 you will only get a closed loop gain of 2/3 of 10 as the simulation does with a peak gain of 6.7 and the -3dB point is 1.6kHz or 60% higher than the Rc*Cfb , yet not double either with the AC couple load of the same value.

The negative feedback lowers the collector output impedance so that the load has less attenuation effect than in the open loop case.

I’m not getting into the proof (others may correct my errors) but using Aol’s of 1e5 or more the closed loop draws negligible input current and the feedback current matched the input current into a virtual null with Vin+. Here that that is not the case although the AC voltage at the base is certainly reduced significantly. The voltage is also attenuated by the low base input impedance of hFE * re.

So due to the low input impedance and low open loop voltage gain,  the closed loop gain is 1/3 less (for hFE=100)than the expected Rf/Rin of 400/39k~10. Also the bandwidth is not reduced as much as expected to ~1kHz because the feedback AC current does not match the generator input AC current. The simulator shows 1.6kHz.